# How to handle response of a POST request in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to POST some data to my ASP.Net MVC Web API controller and trying to get it back in the response. I have the following script for the post:

```
 $('#recordUser').click(function () {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'api/RecordUser',
    data: $("#recordUserForm").serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (useremail) {
        console.log(useremail);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, err) {

    },
    complete: function (xhr, status) {
        if (status === 'error' || !xhr.responseText) {
            alert("Error");
        }
        else {
            var data = xhr.responseText;
            alert(data);
            //...
        }
    }
 });
});
```

The problem with this script is that whenever I try to post the data, the jQuery comes back in "error" instead of "success".

I have made sure that there is no problem with my controller. I can get into my api method in debug mode whenever the request is made and can see that it is getting the data from the POST request and is returning it back. This controller is quite simple:

```
 public class RecordUserController : ApiController
 {
     public RecordUserEmailDTO Post(RecordUserEmailDTO userEmail)
     {
         return userEmail;
     }
 }
```

I am not sure how I can get jQuery to print out any useful error messages. Currently when I try to debug the jQuery code using Chrome console it shows an empty xhr.responseText, nothing in "err" object and "status" set to "error" which as you see is not quite helpful.

One more thing that I have tried is to run the following code directly from the console:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'api/RecordUser',
    data: {"Email":"email@address.com"},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (useremail) {
        console.log(useremail);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, err) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log(err);
        console.log(status);
        alert(err.Message);
    },
    complete: function (xhr, status) {
        if (status === 'error' || !xhr.responseText) {
            alert("Error");
        }
        else {
            var data = xhr.responseText;
            alert(data);
        }
    }
});
```

i.e. using the same script without actually clicking on the button and submitting the form. Surprisingly, this comes back with the right response and I can see my data printed out in console. For me this atleast means that my Web API controller is working fine but leaves me with no clue as to why it is not working on clicking the button or submitting the form and goes into "error" instead of "success".

I have failed to find any errors in my approach and would be glad if someone could help me in getting a response back when the form is posted.

Comment: why are you using the `complete` callback?  That one is used for both success _and_ error.  In any event (no pun intended), it's better these days to use deferred `.done`, `.fail` and `.always`

Comment: You can also try using $.post() - it's a shorthand method for $.ajax() specifically for a post action.

Comment: @Alnitak, good catch. I just removed complete callback and my code is working now. Although I remember that previously it was not working before I had put the complete after reading some answers on SO on trying to print out error message. But I guess I was not calling the success correctly then as I was calling it without an argument - not sure if that was the cause or something else was wrong. Thanks for looking into this. :)

Comment: @SurrealDreams I first tried with $.post then when it was not working I tried the $.ajax and now after removing complete its working

Comment: Good, I'm glad you figured it out.  @Alnitak, you should post that as an answer so sstaq can accept it.

Comment: One thing that is intriguing to me is why the original code works from the console but not when the form is posted and works only when the "complete" callback is removed?

Comment: @sttaq: And as an FYI, if you find yourself banging your head against the keyboard trying to use AJAX with `ICollection<T>`, try setting `traditional:true`. (example seen [here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/jquery_posting_to.ashx))

Comment: @SurrealDreams TBH I can't see what's actually wrong with the OP's code.  I only pointed out the `.complete` callback because it's an unusual pattern - the OP was trying to use logic within that method to detect success/failure when there's already perfectly good methods for those.

Comment: @Alnitak you pointed me to solve my problem, and I see it as an answer. I will still wait for sometime for you to post an answer and if possible an explanation of why it was working in console only with `complete` callback. Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As suggested by Alnitak, I was using `complete` callback along with `success` and `error` ones. Removing `complete` from my code fixed the issue.

Thanks to Alnitak.